# How can I get a line break when using the output command with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and I wrote a very simple program to test a while loop.
My problem is, I do not know how to do line break with my code. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scores = [60, 50, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
var output;
var i = 0;
while (i < scores.length) {
  output = "Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i] ;
  document.write(output);
  i = i + 1;
}
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, very simple. But, when I ran my code, it was no line break. It was very ugly.
Could you please give me some ideas to repair it or more? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the `<br>` element to output a line break in HTML. Or put the text into a `<pre>` element which preserves the whitespace

Comment: `document.write('<br>');`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scores = [60, 50, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
var output;
var i = 0;
while (i < scores.length) {
  output = "</br> Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i] ;
  document.write(output);
  i = i + 1;
}
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to assign a value to the output variable since you're not using it.

Use `let` or `const` instead `var` read more about it here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Template literals are much cleaner than concatenation read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const scores = [60, 50, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
    let i = 0;
    while (i < scores.length) {
      const output = `Bubble solution #${i} score: ${scores[i]} <br />`;
      document.write(output);
      i++;
    }
  </script>
  <body></body>
</html>
```